# Is there a single source for the basics of cooking (sauces, herbs, oil usage, etc)?

Tags: resources

I'm a decent cook but I know that there are huge gaps in my knowledge of the fundamentals of cooking.  I assume that aspiring chefs learn a great deal of this in culinary school but I was hoping that there might be a book or resource for explaining not only the "hows" of making things like a good mayonnaise but also the "whys".

So is there a book or cookbook thats considered best in class for the basics of cooking?

Comment: Should be a community wiki since everyone might have a different opinion on which book is the 'best' book.

Comment: @Kyra: Please flag for Mod Attn instead of commenting. (new approach) Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

I find that anything Cooks Illustrated puts out usually has a decent list of "whys" and have been garnering them up over the years.  Unfortunately this can leave you something of a specialist with deep knowledge on whatever their articles cover, but if you want to learn the why of something, they are a great source.

For baking in particular [Ratio](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416571728) is an excellent book.

Comment: Cooks illustrated is great. The Best Recipe is the book that really taught me how to cook with all their discussion of **why** and not just **how**.

Answer (score 3):

[Harold McGee](http://www.curiouscook.com/cook/home.php) - "[On Food and Cooking](http://www.curiouscook.com/cook/on_food.php)"

Comment: While this is a wonderful book, I worry that it may confuse or intimidate the novice cook who isn't ready for the details that McGee gives.

Comment: @Martha - I originally bought the book 10 years ago as a "novice". And Brett said that he is already a decent cook. So, I think it fits his question well.

Comment: @wdypdx22 Okay. I withdraw my reservation. (I wasn't sure, so I didn't down-vote -- just comment.)

Comment: This book is fascinating, but I think it's a bit too sciencey and abstract to directly apply to the kitchen in most cases. I recently heard an interview with McGhee where he admitted this, which is why he's got a new book coming out. The new book looks like it would probably answer this question. http://www.amazon.com/Keys-Good-Cooking-Making-Recipes/dp/1594202680/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpt_2

Comment: Phenomenal book, and I think everyone who has an interest in a deep understanding of how cooking works should have it, but I also agree it isn't necessarily the technique book that @justkt might have in mind. Looking forward to his new book.

Comment: Very good book. As you say, not very hands-on.